# Is there a specific way to make this code better for a beginner in java?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class hello {
  
    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        int k=0;        
        System.out.println("Enter the number of times for a sentence to loop.\n");

        Scanner i = new Scanner( System.in);
        int j = i.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter the sentence to be looped. \n");
        Scanner sentence = new Scanner(System.in);
        String sent = sentence.nextLine();

        while (k < j ) {
            System.out.println(sent);            
        }
    }
}
```

This is just a program to take a sentence from a user and then print it the number of times the user requires it.
Just started learning it. I have a bit of experience in C , but this seems a bit too tedious could i use any other options ?

Comment: This does not work since you do not increment `k`, you should use a `for` loop instead of a `while` loop and you can remove `sentence` and use `i` again, remove some newlines because this is just bloated...

Comment: Also: no need for two `Scanner`s.

Comment: following naming conventions would be a good start

Comment: got ya im gonna look up naming convention rules and use a for loop for it cause it would make it easier , thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of things that could be improved. Firstly, the code doesn't even work properly since `k` is never incremented (causes an infinite loop).

```
while (k < j ) {
    System.out.println(sent); 
    k++;           
}
```

Also, you only need one Scanner object to read user input. Creating a second one is just waste of memory and makes the code more confusing to read.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
int x = scanner.nextInt();
int y = scanner.nextInt(); //we can use the same object for a different variable.
```

In Java, class names should always start with an uppercase letter. This is to differentiate objects/classes from methods (which should start with a lowercase letter). This makes the code easier to read.

```
public class Hello {
```

Another thing, when you know exactly how many times you want to loop, it's better to use a `for` loop.

```
for(int k=0; k<j; k++) {
    System.out.println(sent);
}
```